# How to keep the georeferencing data from ArcGIS when importing rasters into Erdas imagine?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, georeferencing, erdas-imagine

I have a bunch of WWII Aerial images that I georeferenced in ArcMap and when I load them in Imagine they are being displayed as plain rasters. I tried the Import Data tool, converted the georeferenced JPG files to IMG files, but still, when I load the IMG files, they do not keep their location.
Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: What do you mean Plain rasters ? Do you mean they showed white in colors ?

Comment: By plain raster I mean they were just like loading a not gereofed raster, one on top of each other. Had encountered the issue with white, but after converting the JPG to IMG format everything was OK.

Comment: JPG format does not preserve the georeferencing. You nedd to export/save your images in jpg2000 or Geotiff or  IMG before doing geometric correction. Then start geoferencing your images and open them in ERDAS

Comment: I do not recommend using Jpg2000, you may have problems with it so I'd suggest you use IMG. Also, what version are you using ?  I'd use Imagine AutoSync, I am not sure if they still have it with their latest software/versions. Do you have WWII Aerial Images known coordinates ? Where is that Aerial photos taken place ?

Comment: @ahmadhanb I have tried this but the error is next: "Spheroid name not found based on the given datum name", I am using RD_New projection,EPSG:28992, which exists in among erdas available projections.

Comment: @PROBERT I am using ERDAS imagine 15.00 build 564. AutoSync Imagine still exists in this version. Seems more advanced that georeferencing in ArcMap. No, I have bought the images from dotkadata.com or RCAHMS with unknown coordinates. Images are showing landscape from 1940-1945 over the Netherlands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made it work by converting it to IMG file format and loading it to Imagine. When I got the error ""Spheroid name not found based on the given datum name", I right cliked the raster, access "Metadata", went to edit menu, access "add/change projection", went to "Custom" tab and in the lower left corner there is a box where you can search for a projection using the EPSG code. Used the code (28992 in my case) and everything was alright after that.